# By what mechanism do `want` and `know` fail to form commands?

Tags: english, semantics, verbs

Verbs like `want` and `know` seem to resist being used in imperative constructions. In particular, it does not seem possible to use them to command people to change their mind about what they want or to learn something.

A sentence like `*Want to eat.` with the intended meaning similar to `You should want to eat.` does not appear grammatical to me.

Similarly, a sentence like `*Know about the history of waffles.` with an intended meaning similar to `Learn about the history of waffles.` also does not appear grammatical to me. I can think of a handful of examples with `know` in the imperative though: `know thyself`, `know your limits`, `know your place`, &c.

Psych verbs like `think` can be used to make commands. `Think about it some more.`

**How would one analyze this failure?** `want`ing and `know`ing are not thought of as volitional psychological states. However, `know` at least does appear to have an imperative which can be used in a few cases.

Comment: "For the final exam, know the history of waffles"?

Comment: _Want_ takes a _have_ clause in default situations, as _She wants her doll_ demonstrates. Any other predicate in its complement needs to have the same features as _have_, specifically, being stative. And _know_ is not a psych verb -- it doesn't describe emotion. Its object must be a piece of information, and an imperative wouldn't work with that because the imperative would convey the information. You can do it with groups (_Know them all by Wednesday!_), but not individual objects (*_Know that 3 times 17 is 51!_).

Comment: @jlawler — Imperative _know_ is typically used by wizards, deities, etc., cf., in KJV, “This **know** also, that in the last days perilous times shall come.” (2Tim.3:1), “And he said unto Abram, **Know** of a surety that thy seed shall be a stranger in a land that is not theirs” (Gen.15:13) — dozens of similar usage in the Bible. Even the most mundane “Know that I'll always be with you” is pretty typical, so I don't understand why _know_ should be put aside from the rest of the verbs as for the ability to form the imperative.

Comment: _Want_ is too neutral, Google gives 1.2 million pages with ‘[desire me](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22desire+me%22&oq=%22desire+me%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i7i30l9.6192j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)’.

Comment: @jlawler I think I'm misunderstanding, because I can think of plenty of examples of "want" with a non-stative complement. "She wants to jump off the diving board" is clearly talking about an event rather than a state for example.

Comment: Know your enemy! Waste not, want not!

Comment: "Want only what you can afford", "Know thy master", "If you  want to succeed, know your way around the platform"

Comment: Those uses by deities and wizards are performative. Syntactically they are imperatives, but the sentence is directly conveying the information which the hearer is required to know, so there is no choice to be made or action (intention) required.

Comment: @jlawler "*Know that your retirement accounts will not be counted for financial aid*." , "*Know that you are loved*" , "*Okay . Know that you have a job to do. Do it, and then help*" , "*Know that your actions and attitude shape the future.*". A few of the 350 "Know that" imperatives on COCA (some of the shorter ones from the first page, some of them are very loooong). They seem okish to me.

Comment: They're all (or most of them) just short for _You should know_, CYA stuff.