# What is a psych verb?

Tags: english, terminology, verbs

As mentioned in [this comment by John Lawler](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/by-what-mechanism-do-want-and-know-fail-to-form-commands?noredirect=1#comment110419_47318) to [this question I asked yesterday](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/by-what-mechanism-do-want-and-know-fail-to-form-commands), `know` is not a psych verb.

**What is a psych verb?** I've heard this term before and vaguely guessed that it was a word describing a psychological state, but that's clearly not right.

I'm also curious whether **psych verbs in English share some common features and if there are tests for psych-verb-hood**.

Comment: Have you [tried](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E2%80%9Cpsych+verb%E2%80%9D&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) googling “[psych verb](https://www.thoughtco.com/psych-verb-definition-1691550)"?

Answer (score -3):

I've never heard the term "psych verb" until now, but it seems you actually were at least half correct. From the examples I've seen, a psych verb is a **transitive verb that expresses the emotion that the subject causes the object or vice versa.** So "to please," "to hate," "to frighten" are all psych verbs, but "to know" is not, since it doesn't refer to an emotion.

Does that help?

Comment: This is only partly correct. See [Doron (2020)](https://openscholar.huji.ac.il/sites/default/files/edit.doron/files/2020_doron_draft_causation_book.pdf).